# Rollback transaction after @Test

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit, spring-test

First of all, I've found a lot of threads on StackOverflow about this, but none of them really helped me, so sorry to ask possibly duplicate question.

I'm running JUnit tests using spring-test, my code looks like this

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)  
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {})
public class StudentSystemTest {

    @Autowired
    private StudentSystem studentSystem;

    @Before
    public void initTest() {
    // set up the database, create basic structure for testing
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() {
    }    
    ...  
}
```

My problem is that I want my tests to NOT influence other tests.
So I'd like to create something like rollback for each test.
I've searched a lot for this, but I've found nothing so far.
I'm using Hibernate and MySql for this

Comment: What do you mean by rollback ?. Cleaning the database ?

Comment: setting it to the exactly the same state it was after executing `initTest`

Answer (score 169, accepted):

Just add `@Transactional` annotation on top of your test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)  
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"testContext.xml"})
@Transactional
public class StudentSystemTest {
```

By default Spring will start a new transaction surrounding your test method and `@Before`/`@After` callbacks, rolling back at the end. It works by default, it's enough to have some transaction manager in the context.

From: [*10.3.5.4 Transaction management*](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-tx) (bold mine):

> In the TestContext framework, transactions are managed by the TransactionalTestExecutionListener. Note that `TransactionalTestExecutionListener` is **configured by default**, even if you do not explicitly declare `@TestExecutionListeners` on your test class. To enable support for transactions, however, you must provide a `PlatformTransactionManager` bean in the application context loaded by `@ContextConfiguration` semantics. In addition, **you must declare `@Transactional` either at the class or method level for your tests**.

Comment: well, I tried this before, and it still doesn't work, maybe ... can the problem be that I didn't define the PlatformTransactionManager, how can I do that?

Comment: @javo: how are you modifying the database? If you are using Jpa/Hibernate/JdbcTemplate/... there must be some `PlatformTransactionManager`. Otherwise how Spring will know about your transactions and database?

Comment: The link in this answer is no longer correct; see [user2418306's answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35943700/325900) for the correct link and more context from the Spring documentation.

Comment: I does not work, each method requires a separate transaction, cant do it for whole class

Comment: I'm testing an insert into a table. With @Transactional, the insert command is not even issued against the database (I can see that because the console has hibernate show-sql true). Works fine in many cases. But one of my tests checks that the database issues a DataAccessException because of a database constraint. In this case the test fails because the rollback happens "in memory" and the database is never called. Solution: use `@Transactional` at the `@Test` method level and not at the class level.

Comment: @PauloMerson you should have an '@After on any DB test classes that does a flush of the entity manager.  This ensures the last DB operation gets pushed to the DB to allow constraints to fail, it will still rollback though

Answer (score 23):

*Aside:* attempt to amend Tomasz Nurkiewicz's answer was rejected:

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

---

Correct and permanent [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#testcontext-tx) to the relevant section of documentation about integration testing.

> To enable support for transactions, you must configure a `PlatformTransactionManager` bean in the `ApplicationContext` that is loaded via `@ContextConfiguration` semantics.

```java
@Configuration
@PropertySource("application.properties")
public class Persistence {
    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @Bean
    DataSource dataSource() {
        return new DriverManagerDataSource(
                env.getProperty("datasource.url"),
                env.getProperty("datasource.user"),
                env.getProperty("datasource.password")
        );
    }

    @Bean
    PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource());
    }
}
```

> In addition, you must declare Spring’s `@Transactional` annotation either at the class or method level for your tests.

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {Persistence.class, SomeRepository.class})
@Transactional
public class SomeRepositoryTest { ... }
```

> Annotating a test method with `@Transactional` causes the test to be run within a transaction that will, by default, be automatically rolled back after completion of the test. If a test class is annotated with `@Transactional`, each test method within that class hierarchy will be run within a transaction.

Answer (score 14):

The answers mentioning adding `@Transactional` are correct, but for simplicity you could just have your test class `extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests`.

Comment: adding annotation '@Transactional' on class level does not work, adding annotation '@Transactional ' separately for each function works,and extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests works too

Answer (score 7):

In addition to adding `@Transactional` on `@Test` method, you also need to add `@Rollback(false)`

Comment: This answers the opposite question, how *not to rollback* a transaction in a test. But it's still good to know, that's what I came looking for.

Answer (score 5):

I know, I am tooooo late to post an answer, but hoping that it might help someone. Plus, I just solved this issue I had with my tests. This is what I had in my test:

My test class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "path-to-context" })
@Transactional
public class MyIntegrationTest
```

Context xml

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
   <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
   <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
   <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
   <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>
```

I still had the problem that, the database was not being cleaned up automatically.

Issue was resolved when I added following property to BasicDataSource

```
<property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false" />
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Well, so you commit your statements manually? Are you sure your data was even written in your database?

Comment: For anyone struggling to understand Spring Transactions, make sure your data source is NOT set to auto-commit or you will drive yourself crazy trying to figure out why @Transactional seems to do nothing.

Answer (score 2):

You need to run your test with a Spring context and a transaction manager, e.g.,

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)  
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/your-applicationContext.xml"})
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager="txMgr")
public class StudentSystemTest {

     @Test
     public void testTransactionalService() {
         // test transactional service
     }

     @Test
     @Transactional
     public void testNonTransactionalService() {
         // test non-transactional service
     }
}
```

See chapter [`3.5.8. Transaction Management`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testcontext-tx) of the Spring reference for further details.

Answer (score 2):

As answered above by the top-liked answer, basically you only need to 2 things below to rollback the transaction takes place in test cases:

- add @Transactional on the test Class
- add **@Rollback** on the Test Case

In case it still doesn't work, kindly double check if your system is using multiple data sources, if so, you also need to specify the expected data source for the transaction based on which DB your SQL will connect to.

Code example:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = Sample.class)
@Transactional(transactionManager = "txManagerXX") // specify txManager here if your system uses multiple sources
public class SampleTest {

    @Test
    @Rollback
    public void test_case_1(){
        ...
    }

}
```

Answer (score -5):

You can disable the Rollback:

```
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = false)
```

Example:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@Transactional
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = false)
public class Test {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @org.junit.Test
    public void menge() {
        PersistentObject object = new PersistentObject();
        em.persist(object);
        em.flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly the opposite what the OP is asking for

Comment: This should have been a comment to the accepted answer.