# testing - How to approach integration tests that create new data

Tags: testing, junit, automated-tests, integration-testing

Say I have a test that asserts whether registration of a new user in the system actually succeeds:

```
RegistrationIntegrationTest#testRegister()
```

Now, this creates a new test user in the actual database, since I want this test to run on the actual environment. This means that the test must not be run all the time, right? How should I approach these kind of tests? Those that use the actual environment of the system and manipulates real data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use one of the following:

1. If possible use an in memmory database like [hsqldb](http://hsqldb.org/), which you can re-create or setup suitably for each TestSuite/TestCase
2. If the methods under test are transactional, run the test case with [spring junit rollback true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626502/rollback-transaction-after-test)
3. If you cannot use 1 or 2, you can write a pre & post test sql script that will setup & then cleanup your db. You can use a framework like [dbunit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Wow. Cool stuff. One more thing, what if the feature is to be integration-tested by a client app? Say, what if a client app wants to create an automated integration test of its implementation of the registration API? Should the servers-side provide a way to determine whether a request is an integration test so it can provide or make use of an in-memory database?

Comment: @JuliousIgmen if you want an integration test of the client, you have two options: 1) create a fake server (and write tests that ensure it has reasonable behavior), or 2) start a real server with a fake or in-memory backend. The first option is less fragile and less flaky; the second covers more code and may require less maintenance