# Why aren't @Transactional and @Rollback rollbacking unit tests?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, junit

I'm an writing unit tests for a DAO, and I am trying to make sure that each test rollbacks any changes made. I've already consulted the answer [Rollback transaction after @Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626502/rollback-transaction-after-test) by user2418306, and have set up the appropriate datasource and transactionmanager beans. However, the @Transactional and @Rollback annotations still do not work - changes made by getCommentBySubreddit_Success() influence getCommentBySubreddit_Fail().

**Gradle**

```
    buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.8.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

group = 'com.subredditstats'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest')
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml', name: 'jackson-module-json-org', version: '0.9.1'
    compile group: 'commons-dbcp', name: 'commons-dbcp', version: '1.4'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '1.4.0.RELEASE'

    // Hibernate
    compile('org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.0.Final')
    /*compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-orm', version: '3.1.1.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-entitymanager', version: '4.1.7.Final'*/

    // SQlite
    compile group: 'org.xerial', name: 'sqlite-jdbc', version: '3.7.2'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate.dialect', name: 'sqlite-dialect', version: '0.1.0'


    testCompile group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version: '1.0.60'
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version: '1.3.148'
    testCompile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-test'
    testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '2.1.0'
    testCompile group: 'com.fasterxml', name: 'jackson-module-json-org', version: '0.9.1'
}
```

**Unit test**

```
    package com.subredditstats.api.statistics;

import com.subredditstats.api.content.ContentController;
import com.subredditstats.api.content.model.Comment;
import com.subredditstats.api.content.model.CommentEntry;
import com.subredditstats.api.helper.DatabaseBean;
import com.subredditstats.api.helper.DatabaseOperation;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.Rollback;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;

import java.util.List;


@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=DatabaseBean.class)
@Transactional()
public class StatisticsDAOTest {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("testDatabase")
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private StatisticsDAO dao;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        dao = new StatisticsDAOImpl(sessionFactory);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown(){

    }

    @Test
    @Rollback(true)
    public void getCommentBySubreddit_Success(){
        // Arrange
        CommentEntry comment1 = new CommentEntry();
        comment1.setSubreddit("a");
        DatabaseOperation.persist(sessionFactory,comment1);

        // Act
        List<Comment> comments = dao.getCommentsBySubreddit("a");

        // Assert
        comments.forEach(comment -> Assert.assertEquals(comment.getSubreddit(),"a"));
    }

    @Test
    @Rollback(true)
    public void getCommentBySubreddit_Fail(){
        // Arrange


        // Act
        List<Comment> comments = dao.getCommentsBySubreddit("a");

        // Assert
        Assert.assertEquals(0,comments.size());
        // This fails since a comment with id "a" already exists in the database, due to the effects of getCommentBySubreddit_Success()
    }
}
```

**DatabaseOperation**

```
public class DatabaseOperation {
public static void persist(SessionFactory sessionFactory,Object object){
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(object);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
}
}
```

**DatabaseBean**

```
package com.subredditstats.api.helper;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import javax.transaction.TransactionManager;

@Configuration
@PropertySource("application.properties")
public class DatabaseBean {

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

   @Bean("testDatabase")
    public SessionFactory createSessionFactory(){
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;
        // A SessionFactory is set up once for an application!
        final StandardServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .configure() // configures settings from hibernate.cfg.xml
                .build();
        try {
            sessionFactory = new MetadataSources( registry ).buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // The registry would be destroyed by the SessionFactory, but we had trouble building the SessionFactory
            // so destroy it manually.
            e.printStackTrace();
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy( registry );
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }



    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return new DriverManagerDataSource(
                env.getProperty("datasource.url"),
                env.getProperty("datasource.user"),
                env.getProperty("datasource.password")

        );
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource());
    }


}
```

**Hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>

        <property name="hibernate.dialect">com.subredditstats.api.database.SQLiteDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.sqlite.JDBC</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlite::memory:</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <!-- add classes to map from here -->
        <mapping class="com.subredditstats.api.content.model.CommentEntry" />
        <mapping class="com.subredditstats.api.content.model.SubmissionEntry"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**application.properties**

```
datasource.url=jdbc:sqlite::memory:
datasource.user=
datasource.password=
```

**CommentEntry**

```
package com.subredditstats.api.content.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name="comment")
public class CommentEntry {

    @Id
    @Column(name="commentId")
    private String commentId;

    private int upvotes;
    private int downvotes;
    private String text;
    private boolean gilded;
    private String author;



    private String subreddit;

    public CommentEntry(){
        this("000000",0,0,
                "text", false,
                "author","subreddit");
    }
    public CommentEntry(String id, int upvotes,
                        int downvotes, String text,
                        boolean gilded,String author,
                        String subreddit){
        this.commentId = id;
        this.upvotes = upvotes;
        this.downvotes = downvotes;
        this.text = text;
        this.gilded = gilded;
        this.author = author;
        this.subreddit = subreddit;
    }

    public Comment createComment(){
        return new Comment(commentId,upvotes,
                downvotes,text,gilded,author,subreddit);
    }

    public static List<Comment> mapToComment(List<CommentEntry> commentEntries){
        List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();
        Iterator<CommentEntry> iterator = commentEntries.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            comments.add(iterator.next().createComment());
        }
        return comments;
    }

    public String getCommentId() {
        return commentId;
    }

    public int getUpvotes() {
        return upvotes;
    }

    public int getDownvotes() {
        return downvotes;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public boolean isGilded() {
        return gilded;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public String getSubreddit() {
        return subreddit;
    }



    public void setCommentId(String commentId) {
        this.commentId = commentId;
    }

    public void setUpvotes(int upvotes) {
        this.upvotes = upvotes;
    }

    public void setDownvotes(int downvotes) {
        this.downvotes = downvotes;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public void setGilded(boolean gilded) {
        this.gilded = gilded;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public void setSubreddit(String subreddit) {
        this.subreddit = subreddit;
    }
}
```

This is my first question in a long time; sorry if I didn't correctly format it

Comment: When you say they 'do not work', what do you mean? Do the tests not behave as expected? Do you get specific errors? Just 'it does not work' is very unhelpful towards the people you want help from.

Comment: you shouldn't open a new session by yourself in `DatabaseOperation`, instead you must use `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` to obtain the session managed by the container.

Comment: @ErikS "However, the Transactional and Rollback annotations still do not work - changes made by getCommentBySubreddit_Success() influence getCommentBySubreddit_Fail()." Every change made by a unit test is affecting other unit tests. I want each unit test to be isolated

Comment: @holi-java I fixed the application to use getCurrentSession(), but that didn't fix the problem of Transactional and Rollback not rollbacking the changes made by each unit test

Comment: @Abbrew hey, you should use [HibernateTransactionManager](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate5/HibernateTransactionManager.html) rather than `DataSourceTransactionManager`. use a `DataSourceTransactionmanager` is that tell spring take care of `javax.sql.DataSource` rather than `Session`.

Comment: @holi-java Thanks. That fixed the problem

Comment: @holi-java Could you put your comment in an answer? That way this question gets an answer.