# @Transactional doesn't rollback on DAO @Test methods

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I have a *MySQL database* created and filled with test-purpose rows. I want to do my DAO unit tests on this database. Each `@Test` is `@Transactional` so a rollback is done after each test. Unfortunately, it is not working as changes are still made to my database.

I'm loading my *Spring* configuration with the following context.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                                                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                                                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
                                                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd"
            xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">  
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />  
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/push_test" />  
        <property name="username" value="push_dao" />  
        <property name="password" value="pushpassword" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
      <property name="dataSource"  ref="dataSource" />    
    </bean>

    <bean id="userPushDAO" class="my.package.userPushDAOImpl">
         <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626502/rollback-transaction-after-test) stackoverflow issue said that I

> must provide a `PlatformTransactionManager` bean in the application context

But even with it (it's the `transactionManager` in my context) nothing happens, my database is still modified and not rollbacked.

Here is my DAO test class

```
public class UtilisateurPushDAOImplTest {

    private static ApplicationContext ctx;

    private static UserPushDAO userPushDAO;


    @BeforeClass
    public static void doSetup() {
        ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("context.xml");
        userPushDAO = (userPushDAO) ctx.getBean("userPushDAO");
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void test() {
         userPushDAO.deleteById("id");
    }
}
```

Am I missing something in my **configuration** or in my **comprehension** on how/what `@Transactional` should work/do ?

Comment: I don't think you need the `@Transactional` at all. According to [the Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testing-tx), "By default, the framework will create and roll back a transaction for each test."

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave even without it, it's still modify my database :/ I think I can leave `@Transactional` there so my code is more understandable

Comment: @Transactional does not roll back everytime. It rolls back only when there is some exception in completing all the operation in a transaction .

Comment: @Devendra from Spring [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testcontext-tx-enabling-transactions) it says it does : "Annotating a test method with `@Transactional` causes the test to be run within a transaction that will, by default, be automatically rolled back after completion of the test."

Comment: Ok I was not aware of this. Then just verify your class is annotated with spring junit runner. I could not see it in your code sample. As it is also in spring doc you provided @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)

Comment: `@Transactional` on tests will only work with the `SpringRunner` as a Unit test runner. It doesn't work if you create the application context yourself.

Comment: @Devendra the issue is when adding the `@RunWith` annotation, I can't load the ApplicationContext anymore as I get a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext`. I will try to fix this and come back to you.

Comment: @M.Deinum oh ok, I will try to load it differently then. I used this method of loading as it was the one working for me. I will try again with an other one

Comment: @M.Deinum as you said, it was because I was creating the application myself and had no `SpringRunner`, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @M.Deinum posted in the comment section,

> `@Transactional` on tests will only work with the `SpringRunner` as a Unit test runner.
>
> It doesn't work if you create the application context yourself.

Also don't forget to add the *transaction schema* into the `context.xml` to be able to load your context file correctly.

**DAO test class**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:/context.xml"})
public class UserPushDAOImplTest {
    
    @Resource(name="userPushDAO")
    private UserPushDAO userPushDAO;

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void test() {
         userPushDAO.deleteById("id");
    }
}
```

**context.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
            xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
            xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">  

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">  
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />  
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/push_test" />  
        <property name="username" value="push_dao" />  
        <property name="password" value="pushpassword" />
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource"  ref="dataSource" />    
    </bean>

    <bean id="userPushDAO" class="my.package.userPushDAOImpl">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```