# @Rollback doesn't work with TestNG's @BeforeClass

Tags: spring, junit4

I am writing test cases by extending AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests class . I need client object which is a common for all test cases. So I have kept it under @beforeclass and I am getting the fake object after persisting it in DB.

As I have kept this transaction under @beforeclass , it hasn't been rolled back and I am not getting how to do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rollback transaction after @Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626502/rollback-transaction-after-test)