# Rolling back a Postgres database using Liquibase in Java

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, kotlin, liquibase

I'm trying to roll back the changes to a postgres table inbetween component tests so each one has a clean db to work with.

I'm using liquibase to set up postgres (the changelog xml to describe the setup and then the liquibase-core Kotlin/Java library to apply it). I'm also using Hibernate to interact with postgres directly. The test framework I'm using is Kotest, using the beforeXXX methods to make sure all the setup happens before the tests run. The database is set up once before everything runs and the idea is to rollback after each test.

From looking in the docs I've found [tagDatabase](https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/community/tag-database.html) and [rollback](https://www.liquibase.org/javadoc/liquibase/Liquibase.html#rollback-java.lang.String-liquibase.Contexts-) seem to be what I need, however when running them they don't seem to actually roll anything back.

The code is roughly as follows (this is just test code to see if it works at all, mind - code would ideally be segmented as I descirbed above):

```kotlin
// 1 - (Pre-all-tests) Postgres Setup
liquibase = Liquibase(
    "/db/changelog/changelog-master.xml",
    ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(),
    DatabaseFactory.getInstance().findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(JdbcConnection(connection))
)

liquibase.update(Contexts(), LabelExpression())

liquibase.tag("initialised")


// 2 - Something is inserted
val newEntity = ThingEntity()

entityManager.persist(
    entity
)

entityManager.transaction.commit()
entityManager.clear()


// 3 - Cleanup
liquibase.rollback("initialised", Contexts())


// 4 - Fetching
entityManager.find(ThingEntity::class.java, id)
```

Thing is, after running `liquibase.rollback` the `newEntity` I persisted earlier is still present. The tag has dissapeared - if I run the `doesTagExist` method it returns true and then false after the rollback so the tag is being removed at least.

Given I'm clearing the entity manager after the commit I don't think it's because it's being cached and as I said the tag is being removed - just not the data.

*Can anyone tell my why the actual transactions (i.e. the persist) aren't being erased?*

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using liquibase in a wrong way. What you are trying to have (rollback of data that is added in unit-test) is something close to what is described here: [Rollback transaction after @Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626502/rollback-transaction-after-test)
And when you are asking liquibase to rollback to some tag it just executes rollback scripts (if any provided) for changesets that were applied after changeset with tag: https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/community/rollbackbytag.html